# Extract a particular line and inside a parenthesis in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Just need to extract a string inside a parenthesis from an output of a command.

The command output something like

```
Some sort of text I dont need
random text (text that I need to extract 123456)
```

I've tried experimenting and what I used is

`command 123 | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1`

output comes out as

```
Some sort of text I dont need
text that I need to extract 123456
```

How can I just output

```
text that I need to extract 123456
```

I need this in just one pipe.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```sh
command 123 |  sed -n 's/.*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p'
```

This removes text outside (And including) the parenthesis and only prints the results if a replacement was done, so it skips printing the first line without the parens.